# Input Box background color not changing in IE

Tags: html, css

In my CSS file, I have defined a class as given below.

```
input.entryFormInputBoxColor:focus
{
    background-color:cyan;
}
```

When I use Firefox (3.5.5), the Input Box background color changes to cyan when there is focus, but it is not changing in IE (6.0). The class is successfully executing in Firefox, and all other classes defined, work well in IE too, but the above given class fails in IE.

Comment: Why support IE? They don't support you. :P

Comment: @Austin: I don't support IE either. But some of my clients are from IE camp.

Comment: Only poking fun, you gotta do what you gotta do. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet Explorer did not support the `:focus` pseudo-class until IE8, and only then when a !DOCTYPE is declared.

Here is a nice overview of CSS compliance from IE6 to IE8:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/

You can overcome this pretty easily with javascript, for example: jQuery's `focus()` and `blur()` events.